# Can not recieve a log message untill the function returns the contro

Tags: python-3.x, logging, pyqt5

I need to show some logs message in a text box (gui based on pyqt5).
But I faced the fact that a new log message does not appear untill the function returns the control to the main function (for this *input()* funcion is used, so *print()* shows a message immediately in the console but *log.info* shows a message only after **Enter** key has been pressed.
How can I see a message from **log.info** immediately?

The example code is here (based on the code from [python-logging-output-on-both-gui-and-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176319/python-logging-output-on-both-gui-and-console)):

```
import sys
import os
import logging
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QWidget, QApplication, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

class ConsolePanelHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent

    def emit(self, record):
        self.parent.write(self.format(record))


class Foo(QWidget):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.textEdit.setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit.NoWrap)
        self.textEdit.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)

        self.btn = QPushButton('Dialog', self)
        self.btn.move(20, 20)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        vbox.addWidget(self.textEdit)

    def write(self, s):
        self.textEdit.setFontWeight(QFont.Normal)
        self.textEdit.append(s)

    def showDialog(self):
        self.counter += 1
        add_log(self.counter)


def add_log(counter):
    log.debug("counter = " + str(counter))
    print("counter = " + str(counter))
    input('press any key') # print() is shown but log.debug is not show


log = logging.getLogger("111")
#logging.basicConfig(
#    level=logging.INFO, format='%(levelname)s: %(filename)s - %(message)s')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    console_panel = Foo()
    handler = ConsolePanelHandler(console_panel)
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(filename)s - %(message)s')) # hide loggin in console
    log.addHandler(handler)

    log.info("Getting logger {0} - {1}".format(id(log), log.handlers))
    console_panel.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: you should not use input() in a GUI, what is the purpose of the input()?

Comment: I the real project I use a function instead of the input(). The function works with images and take enough much time. So, I want to the log message before the function starts but actually I see the log after the function has been complited. Here the input() is just an example.

Comment: You must complete this task in another thread, since your task takes a long time and is blocking.